# my code on finger Touch draw in a specific layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I want to draw lines on a layout following my finger movement. there is a parent layout with background image and a child of relative layout with id "relayForDraw" which has one image view . I want , when my finger move on child layout then draw lines on this. I applied some code but it is not working 
code is here ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

RelativeLayout forDraw;
ImageView imgV;
Bitmap bitmap;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;

float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    forDraw = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relayForDraw);
    imgV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    float dw = forDraw.getWidth();
    float dh = forDraw.getHeight();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas();
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imgV.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        downx = event.getX();
        downy = event.getY();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        upx = event.getX();
        upy = event.getY();
        canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
        imgV.invalidate();
        downx = upx;
        downy = upy;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        upx = event.getX();
        upy = event.getY();
        canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
        imgV.invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

and my xml file is here

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back1"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relayForDraw"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="112dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

it is throwing this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing on an 'empty' canvas.
Replace:

```
canvas = new Canvas();
```

with:

```
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Comment: but it still throwing exception. Is i wrote other code right?

Comment: @user3652702 What exception? Please edit the question.